# ASMX webservice when using HttpModule has request.forms.count as zero

Tags: c#, ajax, asmx

I am using an ASMX webservice with a `HttpModule` and I am trying to edit the parameters, when I set the page that send the request via json's body to `validateInput=false`, I get a `Request.Form.Count` of zero, but it still passes the method parameters on to the actual method after it passes the `HttpModule`, is there something that I am missing?

The service is running from a .net 4 webforms application and is mainly used by the webforms.

```
if (request.HttpMethod == "POST")
{
    if (request.Form.Count > 0)
    {
        SanitizeCollection(request.Form);
    }
}
```

Using the above code in the handler does not reach as the Form.Count is always 0,
An example of the Ajax that calls the service is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceName + "/" + div,
    data: "{'div':'" + div + "', 'currentPageString':'" + currentPage + "', 'pageSizeString':'" + pageSize + "','filter':'" + filter + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processdata: true,
    success: function(msg) {
        ServiceSucceeded(msg, div);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        ServiceFailed(msg);
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have a few question relating to this same issue. All have 0 answers and 0 upvotes. I think this should tell you something about the quality of your questions. You are not giving a good description of what you actually want to achieve. What kind of app is using the service? What is it sending? Why do you want to intercept and change the input to the service?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, basically I ask the question which are different from the milestones I hit, I have to secure a site that mainly uses ajax calls to an ASMX webservice for almost all its inputs and outputs, So i ended up creating an HttpModule to handle it but now my forms object always has zero objects though the parameters are successfully passed to the relevant methods.

Comment: That's because a web service request does not have a content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and the posted content does not have the standard query format (x=1&y=2).

Comment: In the http module, try Request.BinaryRead() all the content, then deserialize it using JsonConvert.Deserialize(). You can then recursively check the values, but I think, cannot change them. Event with a form, you have to hack into Request.Form NameValueCollection object to make it read/write to change the values posted by the client, which we had to do in one of our projects..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I go about accessing the posted Data then?

Comment: As I mentioned. You could check the content-type, and if it is application/json, BinaryRead() and then deserialize the content (because you know that it is json). But you cannot change the posted data which will later on be passed to the web service. You can stop the execution with a meaningful exception though. If the content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, you can continue with the current implementation of yours. But again, the Request.Form is a readonly collection and will throw an exception if you try to set the sanitized value back. There is a hack for that though.

Comment: I am able to set that data by using reflection to remove the readonly flag, I have been successful in changing the parameter values, I will try the above posted suggestion and get back to you as soon as I can.